# How to get a TextView from other class

Tags: android

Suppose, I have a MainActivity class. This class has a TextView.
Then i write a new class to process this TextView.
How to get the TextView from the MainActivity to process.
Thank you!

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

TextView txtMsg;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    txtMsg = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtMsg);
    new BackgroundAsyncTask(getApplicationContext());}
```

Another class

```
public class BackgroundAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Integer, String, Void>{

TextView textView;
Context context;
public BackgroundAsyncTask(Context context){
    this.context = context;
}
@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Integer... params) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    textView = (TextView) context.findViewById(R.id.txtMsg); //here has an error }
```

Comment: why you need textView in `BackgroundAsyncTask` ?

Comment: If you need to change any text in TextView, better to return the value from BackgroundAsyncTask

Comment: Try to pass your TextView content to process instead of TextView reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways. I am explaining two way here...

**1)** Write your BackgroundAsyncTask class in MainActivity.class instaead of creating new class, so that you can easily use TextView object.

**2)** Pass TextView object with parameter of BackgroundAsyncTask Constructor.

Like this

**Call BackgroundAsyncTask from  your MainActivity**

```
new BackgroundAsyncTask(MainActivity.this, textView);
```

**Your BackgroundAsyncTask Constructor**

```
public BackgroundAsyncTask(Context context, TextView textview){
    this.context = context;
    this.textview = textview;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to process the `TextView` value, you can pass the value as :

```
public class BackgroundAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, Void>{

TextView textView;
Context context;
public BackgroundAsyncTask(Context context){
    this.context = context;
}
@Override
protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
    String textBoxValue= params[0];
}
```

You can call this as :

```
new BackgroundAsyncTask(context).execute(textView.getText());
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the constructor method of Class BackgroundAsyncTask to:

```
public BackgroundAsyncTask(Context context, TextView textView){
    this.context = context;
    this.textView = textView;
}
```

And in your onCreate() method:

```
...
new BackgroundAsyncTask(getApplicationContext(), textView);
```

Answer (score 0):

Create global instance outside your application.

```
public class CommonsData{
    public static TextView tvYourTextView;
}
```

Use this as declaration in the class where you wish to declare it.

```
CommonsData.tvYourTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtMsg);
```

And use any where within your application scope, don't forget to add a null check before use.

Answer (score 0):

#### I dont know why you need to use textView in doInBackground method. Because **doInBackground** method **`do not have an access to UI thread!!!`** Use all calls of UI elements in  `onPostExecute`,`onPreExecute`, `onProgressUpdate`.

`findViewById` is a method of Activity. so use **this** instead.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

TextView txtMsg; 
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    txtMsg = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtMsg);
    new BackgroundAsyncTask(this);}
```

Another class

```
public class BackgroundAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Integer, String, Void>{

TextView textView;
Activity context;
public BackgroundAsyncTask(Activity context){
    this.context = context;
}
@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Integer... params) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    textView = (TextView) context.findViewById(R.id.txtMsg); //no errors }
```